# Table auto reset after update

Tags: qooxdoo

I have little problem with updating table cells in a table:

after clicking button one of my cell is updating (data is sent to db, after that im updating table by getting values from db again) everything is working fine, but:

```
rows.push(qx.lang.Object.getValues(data[i])); 
tableDM.setData(rows);
```

After that table is resetting its settings so for example if one of my columns is set to ascend after update its reset to default value.

Is there any possibility to turn off that reset?
Maybe just do everything in other way?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in [Qooxdoo playground](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5.1/playground/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `qx.ui.table.model.Simple` the setData method has a second boolean parameter `clearSorting`. [see the api here here](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.model.Simple~setData!method_public)

```
rows.push(qx.lang.Object.getValues(data[i])); 
tableDM.setData(rows, false);
```

Comment: It didn't actually solve my problem but still helped a lot, thx I'm really blind :)